# How to get/access field values while inside hook_block_view?

Tags: 7, entities, blocks

I want to access the values of my field inside `hook_block_view()`.

I tried with [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), and [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) with no luck.

By the way the block is showing in a page. Is there a way to get the values set in the content type field settings?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: May you show the code you are using? If you want to get the value of a field, `field_get_items()` is the right function. Which arguments did you pass to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need information about the field itself and not about its instances (neither globally nor in the context of a given entity).

Hence, you would want to do a:

```
$field = field_info_field('field_my_field');
$keys = array_keys($field['settings']['allowed_values']);
// $keys will now have the set of unique keys for your options as set from
// the field settings page. Eg. Alsace, Aquitaine etc.
```

`field_my_field` is the unique name of your field that you have also attached to a content type. To find this out, ensure the *Field UI* module is enabled, go to the *Manage fields* page for your content type and look up the *Name* column for the field in question.

If you are interested in knowing how the values you had set from the settings form go here, check out `list_field_settings_form()`. [Here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) is a link to the documentation of `field_info_field()` as well.